# Gap at the right sideof the page after using user-scalable in mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have used meta tag as `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>` after using this the page showing white space on right side. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: provide sample code

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"
/>  html, body{
 width: 101%;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}